# How to join two Dstream in spark streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

There is a system producing data to two kafka topic at the same time.

For example:
step 1: system create one data e.g. `(id=1, main=A, detail=a, ...)`.

step 2: data will be split to two part e.g. `(id=1, main=A ...)` and `(id=1, detail=a, ...)`.

step 3: one will send to **topic1** and the other will send to **topic2**

So I want to combine two topic's data using spark streaming:

```
data_main = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum='', groupId='', topics='topic1')
data_detail = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum='', groupId='', topics='topic2')

result = data_main.transformWith(lambda x, y: x.join(y), data_detail)
# outout:
# (id=1, main=A, detail=a, ...)
```

But think about this situation:

`(id=1, main=A ...)` maybe in `data_main`'s batch1 and `(id=1, detail=a, ...)` maybe in `data_detail`'s batch2.
They are very close but not in same batch time.

How to deal with this case? Thanks a lot for any advise

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried windowing ? 
Because windowing will help to look back and see data that came in other batch intervals as well .

Windowing  allows you to apply transformations over a sliding window of data.

Every time the window slides over a source DStream, the source RDDs that fall within the window are combined and operated upon to produce the RDDs of the windowed DStream. So basically you can combine data from multiple batch intervals